# Can a normalised data have 'created' in all tables - or does it have to be its own 'created' table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, normalization

I'm creating a normalised database, but all the tables have a 'created' and 'modified' in the column. Is this allowed, or should 'created' be its own table?!

```
USERS
user_id,
first_name,
last_name,
email,
password,
created,
modified,

PRODUCTS
product_id,
product_name,
price,
description,
created,
modified,

CATEGORIES
category_id,
category_name,
created,
modified,
```

Comment: *"Is this allowed"* - It's your server/DB.

Comment: @Fred -ii I think he wanted to know is this best way to build such structure tables

Comment: This is a "primarily opinion-based" question. @sergio

Comment: seems sensible, user wont be created at the same time as a product as a category

Comment: Another thing to consider is, you'll be using more than just `WHERE` in your queries. One of which will be `JOIN` etc. so, more work there but I'm sure you've thought about that. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

that is a correct approach. the attributes created and modified belong to each modelled entity. the fact that the fields have the same name is NOT a reason to take them out to a common table. that would be actually wrong because it refers to different properties of different entities, in spite of the common names.